# Mock proxy server on local (With fiddler and windows firewall)

Tags: windows, proxy, reverse-proxy

My clients are using a proxy server on their corporation,and I want to set up dev environment for testing development related to proxy issues. 
So, I want to set up a proxy server which blocks all port 80 requests, unless the request is requested by the proxy server.
This is what I tried:

1. Installing fiddler2 on port 8888.
2. Setting up two rules on windows firewall:

   - Block all port 80 requests.
   - Allow all requests from fiddler exe.

Then, I opened FF and changed the proxy server to be 127.0.0.1:8888.
Unfortunately, the requests from the fiddler are still blocked. 
What am I doing wrong?
Is there other program which do that easier? (Tried also with CCProxy without success).

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer [this great post](https://github.com/mapbox/mason/wiki/Windows:-Simulate-an-enterprise-proxy-on-a-single-developer-machine):

1. Block all the outbound connections on the firewall.
2. Allow request from fiddler.exe